# Permissions for apps from unknown sources

Tags: unknown-sources

When installing an app from unknown sources, does it have to ask for specific permissions like regular apps or is every permission granted by default?

Comment: I believe part of it depends upon which API is targeted by the app.

Comment: @Firelord but what you mean isn't specific to the installation source – it's rather if an app supports "runtime permissions" (Android 6+) or not, regardless whether it's installed from Play, F-Droid or via ADB. OP is rather confused about the "dangers and side-effects" of the "unknown sources" option. Good point, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What permissions are granted is not depending on the source. If you sideload apps directly on the device via "unknown sources" (e.g. by using a [third-party market](/tags/alternative-markets/info) app such as F-Droid or Aptoide), Android's package installer will pop up and ask you to confirm, showing basically the same permission list Playstore shows (i.e. a quite abbreviated) for the "all-or-nothing" part (i.e. permissions that cannot be granted at runtime). Runtime permissions are then asked the same way as with all other apps, whenever you use a functionality needing them.

The first confirmation is only skipped if you install apps via `adb install` or `adb pm install`. Runtime permissions will always be dealt with in the very same way: whenever needed.